# Error while creating new Maven project in Eclipse (Tried all possible answers from StackOverflow & google with no luck)

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, windows-server-2016

- Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 64-bit
- Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (latest)
- Java: JDK 14 SE
- Proxy: No

I get this below error in a specific VM but NOT on any other VM's (Works in Windows 10 VM), I am sure it's because of some network configuration in my VM I get the below error but unable to figure out the cause of the issue. It'll be really helpful if anyone could find the cause of the issue.

**Observation 1:** Eclipse able to connect with Maven repo and download the basic jar files, I am able to see those in local repo.

**Observation 2:** Tried different Network connections options Direct/Manual/Native with no luck

**Eclipse Network Connections Screenshot:**
[image: Network Connections]

**Eclipse Error 1**
[image: Error 1]

**Eclipse Error 2**
[image: Error 2]

**Error Log**
[image: Error Log]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of folder access rights. Moving the **.m2** local repository from **C:** drive to another drive solved the issue.